# R2 - contribution of explanatory variables x1, x2 and x3 to the variance of the explained variable y

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, r-squared

I wish to look at the contribution of explanatory variables x1, x2 and x3 to the variance of the explained variable y.

To summarize the contribution of the explanatory variables alone to the explained variable variance, I calculated the coefficient of determination (R2-xi) of the explanatory variable xi for the model including only the explanatory variable i.

E(y│xi)= α+βi ×xi +ε

Could someone kindly explain to me why the three individual R2-xi (for E(y│x1), E(y│x2) and E(y│x3)) don’t sum up to 100% (R2-x1 + R2-x2 + R2-x3 > 100%). Is that normal?
Thank you very much

Comment: If x1, x2 and x3 have non-zero covariance I would expect this result.

Comment: You seem to make ambiguous statements. kindly indicate whether you are interested in all three variables and or individually R-square of each varible separately.

Comment: Please indicate a bit of your data and your goal for the analysis.